# How does this python yield function work?

Tags: python, yield

```py
def func():
    output = 0
    while True:
        new = yield output
        output = new


genr = func()
print(next(genr))
print(next(genr))
print(next(genr))
```

output:

> 0
>   None
>   None

What i thought is:

1. `genr=func()` return a generator, but does not actually run it.
2. First `print(next(genr))` run from the begining of func to `yield output`, but not yet assign back to `new`,so output `0` make sense.
3. Second `print(next(genr))` start from assigning `output` back to `new`，and next line `output = new` make both `output` and `new` to 0, next execute `yield output` should return 0, but why it return `None` actually?

Comment: Don't assign `new` to `yield output`. The result of that operation is `None`

Comment: You mean `yield output` won't be assign back to `new`? do you have any reference information, thank you.

Comment: Have a search for coroutines

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A [*yield*](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement) statement is used like *return* to return a value but it doesn't destroy the stack frame (the part of a function that knows the current line, local variables, and pending try-statements).  This allows the function to be resumed after the yield.

When you call a function containing yield, it returns a ["generator"](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-generator) that allows you to run code up to a yield and then to resume it from where it left off.

```
>>> def squares(n):
        for i in range(n):
            yield i ** 2

>>> g = squares(5)             # create the generator
>>> g
<generator object squares at 0x106beef10>
>>> next(g)                    # run until the first yield
0
>>> next(g)                    # resume after the yield
1
>>> next(g)                    # resume after the yield
4
>>> next(g)                    # resume after the yield
9
>>> next(g)                    # resume after the yield
16
>>> next(g)                    # looping is terminated with a StopIteration
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    next(g)                    # looping is terminated with a StopIteration
StopIteration
```

Interestingly, a generator can accept values using the *send()* method.  To prime the pump for such a generator the first call should be *next()*.

```
>>> def capitalize():
        word = 'start'
        while word != 'quit':
            word = yield word.capitalize()

>>> g = capitalize()
>>> next(g)                      # run to the first yield
'Start'
>>> g.send('three')              # send in a value to be assigned to word
'Three'
>>> g.send('blind')              # send in a value to be assigned to word
'Blind'
>>> g.send('mice')               # send in a value to be assigned to word
'Mice'
>>> g.send('quit')               # send in a control value
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#28>", line 1, in <module>
    g.send('quit')               # send in a control value
StopIteration
```

What you've figured-out in your example is that `next(g)` is really the same as `g.send(None)`.

Here's what [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions) have to say:

> The value of the yield expression after resuming depends on the method
>   which resumed the execution. If __next__() is used (typically via
>   either a for or the *next()* builtin) then the result is *None*.
>   Otherwise, if *send()* is used, then the result will be the value passed
>   in to that method

Here's a session that makes all of that visible:

```
>>> def show_expression():
        for i in range(5):
            word = yield 10
            print('The word is %r' % word)

>>> g = show_expression()
>>> next(g)
10
>>> g.send('blue')
The word is 'blue'
10
>>> g.send('no')
The word is 'no'
10
>>> g.send('yellow')
The word is 'yellow'
10
>>> next(g)
The word is None
10
>>> g.send('done')
The word is 'done'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#44>", line 1, in <module>
    g.send('done')
StopIteration
```

Hope that explains all the mysteries from first principles :-)

Comment: So, in my problem code, the `new = yield output` statement does not execute completely? just `yield output` without assigning back the result to new?

Comment: @user2706322 Yes, though I would say it a bit differently.  The ``yield output`` returns the output value and *suspends* the execution.  Later, when you write ``g.next()`` which is equivalent to ``g.send(None)``, the execution completes, with the passed-in *None* value becoming result of the expression and being assigned to *new*.   In other words, it executes completely but is broken into two steps, one before the *next* and one after.

Comment: I still have 1 quesion, why first g.next() let `yield output` produce `0` and second let produce `None`?    In the second `g.next()`, the output should still be `0` doesn't it?

Answer (score 4):

The result of a [yield expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr) is the value sent in by the [generator.send()](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.send) function, and `next(gen)` is equivalent to `gen.send(None)`. So `new` receives the value `None` each time you call `next()`.

If you do this instead:

```
gen = func()
print(next(gen))     # gets the first value of 'output'
print(next(gen))     # send in None, get None back
print(gen.send(10))  # send in 10, get 10 back
print(gen.send(20))  # send in 20, get 20 back
```

you'll get this output:

```
0
None
10
20
```

Comment: So, the `new = yield output` statement does not execute completely? just `yield output` without assigning back the result to `new`?